# Homotopy construction

Tags: homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Let $f$ be a loop based at $x_0$ and $c_{x_0}$ be the constant loop. Construct an explicit homotopy between $f$ and $f\cdot c_{x_0}$.

I have seen that $$F(s,t)=\begin{cases}f\big(\frac{s}{1-\frac{t}{2}} \big)\ \ \text{if}\ 0\leq s\leq 1-\frac{t}{2} \\
x_0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{if}\ 1-\frac{t}{2}\leq s\leq 1\end{cases}$$ is a homotopy between $f$ and $f\cdot c_{x_0}$. But how to get that homotopy? Is there any explicit way to construct that?

Comment: What do you mean by "explicit"?  The formula you've written is as explicit as you can get without specifying $f$.  If you're asking how you might come up with this homotopy, have you taken a look at the diagrams on page 6 of [May's *Concise* book](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf)?

Comment: Thanks for replying. My question is, how to get the homotopy $F(s,t)$ from the homotopy diagram.

Comment: From the diagram, we see that there is a triangle in the $(s,t)$-plane in which the homotopy has constant value $x_0$.  This is the second line of the formula.  On the remaining trapezoid, we do the loop $f$, but gradually (linearly) quicker and quicker, which is the first line of the formula.  The line dividing the two regions is given by the equation $s = 1 - t/2$, which gives you the bounds in the two cases.